# Insert integer if doesn't exist, increment if already exists in Firebase realtime database Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to generate a random integer between 1 & 5 and insert the integer in Firebase database when `saveData()` is called first time. After the first time, when `saveData()` is called the integer should be incremented(new generated integer should be added to previously inserted integer). Every time `saveData()` is called below code over writes the previously inserted integer instead of incrementing the integer.

```
protected fun saveData() {
    val randomInt = Random().nextInt((5-1) + 1)//generates int between 1 & 5
    val user = User(randomInt)

    val currentUser = mAuth?.currentUser
    val uid: String = currentUser!!.uid
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid)

    ref.setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Successful" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

User.kt

```
class User(val randomInt: Int)
```

Structure which I am getting in firebase database after `saveData()` is called for lets say 3 times and lets say random integers generated each time are 2, 1 and 4:

```
    my-firebase-app-5c40
       |__-Lhi7dewd7878dew
               |__randomInt: 4 //2 is overwritten 1 and 1 is overwritten by 4
```

Whereas I want it to be:

```
        my-firebase-app-5c40
       |__-Lhi7dewd7878dew
               |__randomInt: 7 //2 + 1 + 4
```

So, in a nutshell I want to increment the value of `randomInt` everytime `saveData()` is called instead of overwriting the previous inserted value which is happening with my current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a [Firebase Database transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), which is the only reliable way to update a property based on its existing value in a multi-user environment. Based on the example in the documentation, your code should look something like this:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid).child("randomInt")

ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Long value = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
        if (p == null) {
            mutableData.setValue(1L);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }
        else {
            mutableData.setValue(value + 1);
        }

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "transaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I am in the right direction, but unfortunately I ran into another issue. Can you please look into it. I created a new question for it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595778/error-unable-to-write-bundle-to-storage-android-firebase-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

This is an integer which you’re trying to save in the database:

```
val randomInt: Int
```

Basically, the random function works properly. So, if you’re trying to save 2 + 1 + 4 in that user’s item, you probably should send the data as string and change the database item to string in order to be able to save as an string.

- However, you’ll also need to change your random function which would return such numbers.

To do that, if you’re getting those numbers after three times, run the random function for three times and then save each value of three times running code and send it as string into the database.

Comment: Use this question logic for running a code multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050410/android-how-to-call-a-method-multiple-times-with-a-delay-between-them

Comment: Thanks. I do not have problem calling the function multiple times. In a nutshell, I want to increment the "randomInt" integer in database with random integer between 1 and 5 everytime "saveData()" is called.